# iOS timed image reload

Tags: ios, uiview, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I have a web cam I'm pulling images from for an iPhone app. I put the code that pulls the image into the view in viewWillAppear. That works pretty well but what I really want is to reload the image every 30 seconds. Is there a setInterval equivalent that I can use to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use:

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(reloadImage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And then have your reload method like this:

```
-(void)reloadImage:{
    //Your reload code
}
```

:)